# InDesign XML Running Head

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm importing data in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
<category>
    <Cat_Title>TITLE</Cat_Title>
    <sub_category>
    <Sub_Cat_Title>SUB TITLE</Sub_Cat_Title>
        <product>
            <Name>PRODUCT NAME</Name>
            <Weekly_Price>£5.00</Weekly_Price>
        </product>
    </sub_category>
    <sub_category>
    <Sub_Cat_Title>SUB TITLE</Sub_Cat_Title>
        <product>
            <Name>PRODUCT NAME</Name>
            <Weekly_Price>£180.00</Weekly_Price>
        </product>
    </sub_category>
</category>
</products>
```

I've managed to get the layout done really nicely and importing well with the XML import functionality, however there is one last thing that I want to do. At the moment, the `Cat_Title` appears at the top of the page when it occurs (using the Keep Options).

What I want is for the title to appear at the top of every page until that category is finished. (The next category then starts on the next page).

Is that possible? Essentially what I need to do is repeat the title at the top of every page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check at running headers : https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/numbering-pages-chapters-sections.html